# Ask element for their events

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

In JavaScript, is there a way to as a element for the events that I can use to add listener.

Something like:

```
element = document.getElementById(id);
console.log(element.listEvents);
```

I'm using a DOM example, but this would be useful in node.js also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such way of retrieving a list of supported events for an element/object.

In case of Node.js you should read the api documentation:
http://nodejs.org/api.html

For HTML elements I would suggest that you search over at MDC, this should be a good starting point:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element#Event_Handlers